# gridview goes back to visible=false when page changes...(and page # issues)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, paging

Probably an easy and simple answer to this, but everywhere I look, the questions are more complicated than my situation...

I've got a gridview which is set to be visible false in the aspx.  If a search returns results, it gets made "visible", however, if there's more than 10 results (set to 10 per page) and the user clicks on one of the page numbers at the bottom, it resets it's visibility to false.  Is there any way around this, short of adding a panel for it to sit on?  seems like there should be a way to do this without adding extra objects to the DOM.

Also, on a related note, those page numbers are spaced out in cells across the bottom, instead of being neatly lined up next to one another.  Is there a simple pagerStyle setting that collects them all in a row?  I've not seen a gridview do this before... in the past its default settings have always placed those numbers neatly in the lower left hand corner... any quick tips?

Comment: Make it visible true in aspx and check. GridView is visible only if there is records in the DataSource after binding. So, if there are no record, then it is not visible by default.

Comment: In your code behind, are you setting it to Visible=true anywhere?

Comment: I set it to visible equals true, and set it to false with no rows... and this seems to be working now between pages... any tips for getting all the page numbers in one cell?

Comment: As for the second part of the question, the canned page numbers at the bottom of the GridView are extremely limited in what you can do with them check out the [GridView.AllowPaging Property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.allowpaging(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.  If you want more flexability, you'll have to roll your own code.

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand one step: gridview is seto visible=false......is not more simple use binding property ? in example **if search = true(has result) then bind gridview else not bind** more simple and flexible no?????